# Synthesize speech in android system webView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, text-to-speech

I need speech synthesizing in the android system webView.
It seems that speechSynthesis is not supported yet. Chrome and Chrome for Android do.

I build a website that can be loaded in a webView inside an app and TTS should also work there.

Is there another way to synthesize speech except of fee-based third party services?

Comment: If you're writing an Android app, text to speech has a library on Android.  You'd just need to get the text out of the webview.  The documentation is at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech

Comment: Thanks, Gabe. Unfortunately, it's not an android app or rather not my android app. My website can be loaded in a webView inside an app.

Comment: Then this isn't an Android question, it's a question about tts in javascript.  You'll be better off asking it that way, you won't find many web developers reading the Android tag.  But if there's a tts api in javascript that webview doesn't support, you're kind of out of luck.  Your next best option may be to record sound files and allow them to stream them from your server.  Or hope that they have screen reading software on their device if they need it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Gabe :) 
Hm, I will take a look at this workaround. But hopefully there will be another option ^^

Comment: Just to point to the source of the problem: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487255